# Adverb inversion with an adjective

Tags: syntax

> It is designed especially for dogs.

Can 'for' qualify 'especially,' but not 'designed'? That is, can the preposition phrase modifies adverb in this case? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The prepositional phrase "for dogs" still qualifies "designed."  "Especially" can be taken to qualify "for dogs"  in turn.